# Clear a database table

Tags: c#, sql

I'm using the following code to clear a database table:

```
public void ClearAll()
{
    SqlCommand info = new SqlCommand();
    info.Connection = con;
    info.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    info.CommandText = "edit_.Clear()";
}
```

Why does it not work?

Comment: What does `edit_.Clear()";` stands for?

Comment: **WHAT** database and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by **many** database systems - **SQL** is **NOT** a database product... stuff like this is very often **vendor-specific** - so we really need to know what **database system** you're using....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute the command, so info.Execute() or info.ExecuteNonQuery().

Answer (score 4):

With a sql command you usually pass a TSQL statement to execute. Try something more like,

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["con"]); 
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Edit_ ";
cmd.Connection = con; 
con.Open(); 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
con.Close();
```

Comment: make sure you set your SQLConnection to whatever your connection string is, and make sure the Table name is Edit_ and that whatever connection settings you are are using has permission to read and write.

Answer (score 1):

Try `info.CommandText='DELETE FROM edit_';`

The CommandText attribute is the TSQL statement(s) that are run.

You also need a `info.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: No, no 'delete from t', 'truncate Table'

Comment: public void ClearAll ( )
   {
   SqlCommand info = new SqlCommand ( );
   info . Connection = con;
   info . CommandType = CommandType . Text;
   info . CommandText = "DELETE * FROM edit_";
   info . ExecuteNonQuery ( );
   }
didnt work:(

Comment: @suffix: Try with `info.CommandText = "DELETE FROM edit_"`. No star `*` character.

Answer (score 0):

1) Decide whether to use a TRUNCATE or a DELETE statement

Use TRUNCATE to reset the table with all its records and indexes:

```
using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    command.CommandText = "TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[Edit_]";
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Use DELETE to delete all records but do not reset identity/auto increment columns

```
using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    command.CommandText = "DELETE FROM [dbo].[Edit_]";
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Note that there is another line in the samples. In the sample you provided the SQL statement never gets executed until you call one of the ExecuteXXX() methods like ExecuteNonQuery().

2) Make sure you use the correct object (are you sure its called `edit_`?). I recommend to put the schema before the table name as in the examples before.

3) Make sure you use the correct connection string. Maybe everything worked fine on the production environment ;-)

Comment: What error do you receive? Use something like SQL Profiler to check if the SQL statement it really executed and provide us with more details...

Comment: I dont receive any error, but i can search from that table, delete from that table and insert but not clear:S

Comment: If you can DELETE, you can also "clear", which is actually not an existing statement but equivalent to DELETE without a WHERE condition.